# React-native FlatList item changes position after update

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have created a flatlist and each item has a button that onPress will change item value. The issue comes up when I change item value, as that item will also unexpectedly fall down to the last position of the flatlist.

This is happening only from React-Native version 57 +

The 55.4 version didnt' run into this problem, but I need to upgrade react-native to 57+.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Here is the sample code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

class List extends Component {

state = {
    currencies: {
        USD: 0,
        EUR: 0,
        GBP: 0,
        BTC: 0,
        CNY: 0,
        AUD: 0,
        JPY: 0
    }
}

render() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                extraData={this.state}
                data={Object.keys(this.state.currencies)}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Row
                    itemValue={this.state.currencies[item]}
                    itemName={item}
                    numberUp={(name) => this.setState({currencies: 
                    {...this.state.currencies,
                     [name] : this.state.currencies[name] + 1}
                     })
                    }
                    />
                )}
            />
        </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
},
itemContainer : {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    margin: 10
},
itemText : {
    fontSize: 30
}
});

export default List;


const Row = (props) => (
<View style={styles.itemContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.itemText}>{props.itemName}  </Text>
    <Text style={styles.itemText}>{props.itemValue}  </Text>
    <Button title="PLUS" onPress={() => props.numberUp(props.itemName)}/>
</View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to append item into the list. that's why it is displaying item at the end of the list.

try below code, I have tried it and it's working:

```
render() {
      return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    extraData={this.state}
                    data={Object.keys(this.state.currencies)}
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <Row
                        itemValue={this.state.currencies[item]}
                        itemName={item}
                        numberUp={(name) => {
                        let currencyList = this.state.currencies;
                        currencyList[name] = this.state.currencies[name] + 1;
                        this.setState({currencies: currencyList})
                        } 
                         }
                        />
                    )}
                />
            </View>
        )
      }
```

Comment: Another useful method for arrays only though, is array.unshift('item') this will insert an item at the start.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wonder why we need to use a different method starting from react native 57.

Comment: I have tried to use this on redux, but is not working. I mean it does update the object property but it doesn't rerender....

Comment: Thanks man, I found a way to make it work with redux, pretty much similar to your solution. So, before mutating the redux state by layers, i simply first mutated the object property, stored it in a variable and then performed the redux state mutation. Thanks again... Apparently was a trivial question, but again, with react native 0.54 i didnt need to use this new object mutation workflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Object doesn't maintain the property order. Thats why order gets changed in your list when you update it. ECMA script defines [object](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) as

> An **object** is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered
>   collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value,
>   object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is
>   called a method.

So to maintain the order its better to use an **array** instead.

```
currencies: [
{currency:USD, value:0},
{currency:EUR, value:0},
{currency:GBP, value:0},
{currency:BTC, value:0},
{currency:CNY, value:0},
{currency:JPY, value:0},
    ]
```